# How to send form data in fetch where values are strings?

Tags: javascript, isomorphic-fetch-api

I'm trying to `PUT` the following data: `{value: false}`.  I'm using isomorphic-fetch and am sending the following:  `JSON.stringify({value: false})`.  The problem is that the server expects all values to be strings.  I tried using FormData and sending that, but the server doesn't understand that for some reason.

Am I better off trying to use a replacer on JSON.stringify that outputs all values as strings?  Or is there a way to have FormData return NVPs instead, where I send that?  Just looking for a snippet on the preferred approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could just go through all the values in the object you're going to pass and call toString() on them before you stringify.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just use `URLSearchParams()` and avoid handling null and arrays when using toString.

```
let qs = new URLSearchParams();

for (let i in data) qs.append(i, data[i]);

const result = qs.toString();
```

Or the wish-js-had-better-immutable-objects:

```
const result = Object.keys(data).reduce((p, c) => {
  p.append(c, data[c]);

  return p;
}, new URLSearchParams()).toString();
```